# Export to excel using Response.TransmitFile() is not working properly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, openxml

I have written some content to an Excel file using OpenXML, and I tried to transmit the file using `Reponse.TransmitFile`, but it is not working. When I debug the code it is not throwing any exception.

```
string filename = "Book1.xlsx";

try {
    System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", Server.MapPath("~/" + filename).Length.ToString());
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/"+filename));
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Comment: Please make sure the path return by Server.Mappah is occrect for you

Comment: Please describe "not working". Is the file corrupt or is it not sending at all?

Comment: it is not sending at all. I am using firefox browser.

Comment: Can you show the full code of your Action?